# Specifying animations and Toolbar items in the resource editor

Tags: codenameone

I'm getting the hang of using themes to change my app's look and feel, but there are still a few mysteries. Right now, in the SocialBoo theme, the button to show the overflow menu is way too small, even though it's the right size in any other theme. Also, the overflow menu pops up with a nice animation on the other themes, but not in the SocialBoo theme. Can anyone tell me how to modify the theme to fix the size of the overflow button and specify an animation for the overflow menu?

Answer (score 0):

SocialBoo is a pretty old demo that still uses the old GUI builder. We are slowly migrating away to the new GUI builder which was slated for the 3.4 release but is currently still considered beta status.

The new GUI builder standardizes on Toolbar which didn't exist when we developed the old GUI builder.

The icons for overflow/side menu can be customized via [theme constants](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html#_theme_constants) specifically `sideMenuImage` and `menuImage`.

Comment: Thank you. The menuImage constant was blank for both themes, but it wouldn't have helped, since the icon shows up the same size. But in the SocialBoo theme, it doesn't fit inside the button drawn behind it. I managed to remove the button image in the resource editor by setting the background image type to [empty]. 
I don't see any way to change the values of theme constants in the resource editor, but I did manage to specify the animations I wanted in code.

Comment: I think that old demo doesn't really use the toolbar and builds it's own title area. The constants are the before last tab in the theme: Unselected, Selected, Pressed, Disabled, Constants & Help.

Comment: Thanks. I found it. That may be from an old demo, but it's a very good-looking theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partly fix this in code like this:

```
Hashtable<Object, Object> newThemeProps = new Hashtable<>();
// I need to start these with @, which tells the addThemeProps() method
// that these are theme constants, not theme properties.
// (The @ character gets stripped out.)
newThemeProps.put("@menuTransitionIn", "bubble");
newThemeProps.put("@menuTransitionOut", "fade");
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(newThemeProps);
```

This gave me the animations I wanted. I still don't know how to change this in the resource file.

As for the buttons, I fixed this in the Resource Editor by opening the TitleCommand style and setting the Background Image type to [empty] in the "..." button. This didn't improve the size of the button, but it removed the too-small button image, so it looks more professional. Here's what it looks like before the fix:

[image: Before]

This is after the fix:

[image: After]

(Yeah, I added another item to the menu, too.)

It retrospect, I could probably have just checked the Derive button in the Background Image tab.

I also changed the TitleCommand foreground color to white (not shown), because the black buttons were practically invisible.

Finally, I changed the FontImage Icons to white with this piece of code:

```
/**
 * The icon created by this method gets passed to the Command constructor.
 *
 * @param icon The FontImage constant for the desired icon
 * @return The icon as an Image.
 */
@Nullable
public static Image createClearMaterialIcon(char icon) {
     materialIconStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
    // materialIconStyle.setBgTransparency(0, true);
    if (icon == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return FontImage.createMaterial(icon, materialIconStyle);
    }
}
```

The transparency of the style needs to be set to zero (transparent). This can be done using the setBgTransparency() call in the line that's commented out, or it can be done by setting the TitleCommand resource's transparency to 0 in the Color tab.

Thank you, Shai, for pointing me in the right direction.